# oracle sql query difficulties

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got a query like

```
             select distinct rel.service_code, gsm.mobile_no
             from service.gsm gsm, service.gsm_relation rel
             where gsm.code = rel.child_service_code(+)
```

which outputs results like

```
       service code     GSM
          (null)    08864124323
           null     05534234234
           null     03244242423
           5000552  02443244324
           (null)   01313131313
           (null)   01233131231
```

Now how can I use the outputted service code, in this case 5000552 to look up in the gsm table like

```
     select mobile_no from service.gsm
     where code = '5000552'
```

which outputs 0773442342 and put this number in the query above instead of the service code. So the desired output in this instance would be

```
       service code     GSM
          (null)    08864124323
           null     05534234234
           null     03244242423
        0773442342  02443244324
           (null)   01313131313
           (null)   01233131231
```

In other words I want to combine these two query into one and get the final result above. So instead of displaying the service code, display the corresponding number to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this with explicit joins, `left outer join` in your case.  Your original query is:

```
select distinct rel.service_code, gsm.mobile_no
from service.gsm gsm left outer join
     service.gsm_relation rel
     on gsm.code = rel.child_service_code;
```

To complete the query, just add another `left outer join` clause:

```
select distinct gsm2.service_code, gsm.mobile_no
from service.gsm gsm left outer join
     service.gsm_relation rel
     on gsm.code = rel.child_service_code left outer join
     service.gsm gsm2
     on rel.service_code = gsm2.service_code;
```

Comment: Hi, great. Just wondering about the 2nd left outer join. Is it joining the whole output from the first left outer join?

Comment: @user3017335 . . . Yes.  It keeps the output from the first two tables and brings in matching rows from the third.